# Creating a Postgres crosstab query and calculating difference between columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tni analysis

I have data in the format

```
Patid | TNT     | date
 A123 | 1.2.    | 23/1/2012
 A123 | 1.3.    | 23/1/2012
 B123 | 2.6.    | 24/7/2011
 B123 | 2.7.    | 24/7/2011
```

And I would like to be able to calculate the difference between two rows like so

```
rowid. | TNT-1. | TNT-2. | difference
A123.  |. 1.2.  | 1.3.   | 0.1
B123.  | 2.6.   | 2.7.   | 0.1

Etc
```

I presume this is a use for the cross tab function in Postgres but am struggling to get results. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your data kind of makes it difficult because there is one 'key' and it is not unique.  For a given PATID, will there only be two entries in this table? Will the DATE always be the same for a given key?  I assume you are looking for the absolute value of the difference (i.e. abs(1.3 -1.2) = abs(1.2 -1.3)), is this correct?

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I've refactored the data to have the set code in data row (i.e TNT-1) and a result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pivot by hand and then take the difference (assuming you always have 2 records for each `Patid` and you don't have to take `date` into account):

```
with cte1 as (
    select
        Patid, TNT, date, row_number() over(partition by Patid order by TNT) as rn
    from Table1
), cte2 as (
    select
        Patid,
        max(case when rn = 1 then TNT end) as "TNT-1",
        max(case when rn = 2 then TNT end) as "TNT-2"
    from cte1
    group by Patid
)
select
    Patid as rowid, "TNT-1", "TNT-2", "TNT-2" - "TNT-1" as difference
from cte2

-------------------------------------
ROWID    TNT-1    TNT-2    DIFFERENCE
A123       1.2      1.3           0.1
B123       2.6      2.7           0.1
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7c6d1/2)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks yes works great. The next step is to account for the factors you mention as I can't always assume that there are only 2 records and I will need to ensure that the difference is only calculated within records in a certain time period. Thanks for this.